# Bootstrap Grid not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am currently designing a site that works fine on Chrome, FF, & IE 9,10 but when I view the site in IE8 thru browserstack it renders terribly.

Code of the section:

```
  <div id="retail_locate" class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div id="retail_btn" class="col-md-4 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="btn-text">Find A Local Retailer</span><span class="icon-map-marker"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
                            <img class="img-responsive shadow" src="images/retailers/retail1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <img class="img-responsive shadow" src="images/retailers/retail2.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
                            <img class="img-responsive shadow" src="images/retailers/retail3.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img class="img-responsive shadow" src="images/retailers/retail4.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img class="img-responsive shadow" src="images/retailers/retail5.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img class="img-responsive shadow" src="images/retailers/retail6.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .container -->
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3. I think whats screwing this up is the col-lg,md etc. The grid is not in effect.

Images: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LfYp.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjFAp.png

Any help would be amazing. This is my first post on Stack and I've searched everywhere for fixes. I included html5shim and respond.js in my header.

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="js/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
   <script src="js/dest/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

I changed the doctype

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"             "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and even added the meta tags

```
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Consider using `respond.js` as IE8 doesn't deal with media queries. (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: have you read the browser support section of the bootstrap documentation? http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers

Comment: Included the respond.js

Comment: Yeah i read the documentation. But I'm trying to see if I can fix this grid system? If you see the pics, I just need those images to be in a proper row.

Comment: Press F12, what is the Document Mode listed as?

Comment: When I press F12 the document mode is in IE8 Standards

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not reconginse media queries and this is probably why nothing is working.  The code I have used in the past and works fabulous is this:

https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Answer (score -1):

Check the non-js solution:

https://github.com/dizzyn/bootstrap-grid-desktop-first

It's a Grid Css Patch